# Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have created this Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface OrganisationRepository  extends JpaRepository<Organisation, Long> {
}
```

but when I use it:

```
organisationRepository.findOne(1L);
```

I have this error:

```
Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend` 'com.cor.de.la.ciutat.Organisation'
```

Comment: I think the problem is within usage of findOne method.
This method come down from QueryByExampleExecutor<T>, therefore usage of this method would be more like : ...findOne(Example.of(1L)).

There is also CrudRepository having 'findOne(ID id)' definition.

Easiest way to make this work tho, would be to define findOneById(Long id) within Your interface.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, your spring-data-jpa version is 2.x. They renamed `findOne()` to `findById()` ([and changed its signature a bit](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findById-ID-)).

The `findOne()` still exists in [QueryByExampleExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/query/QueryByExampleExecutor.html#findOne-org.springframework.data.domain.Example-), but it can be used only for [queries by example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example), not for searching by primary key.

So, use this:

```
organisationRepository.findById(1L).orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.orElse` as  findOne returns an `Optional<S>`

```
organisationRepository.findOne(1L).orElse(null);
```